# SharePoint Server 2019 Search application content sources

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, sharepoint-search, 2019, content-source

When I am trying to open SharePoint Server 2019 Server search application content sources, getting the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong
> The security timestamp is invalid because its creation time ('2020-12-04T16:52:58.353Z') is in the future. Current time is '2020-12-04T16:47:48.529Z' and allowed clock skew is '00:05:00'.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Sincerely
Farook Golam

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that all servers in your SharePoint farm have the same system time and time zone settings.

Answer (score 0):

All servers joined to Active Directory in your environment should be synchronizing time from your Active Directory Domain Controller(s) with the DC holding the PDC Emulator role synchronizing from an external source (i.e. a source from pool.ntp.org).

If you've virtualized your SharePoint environment, make sure to check the underlying hypervisor OS' time sync (i.e. Hyper-V), as well.

[Windows Time service tools and settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings)

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day. Cheers....